# How can I use np.sum to get the index of a particle without using a for loop?

Tags: numpy, indexing, resampling, cumulative-sum

I am trying to distinguish the index of a certain particle in my array. First I generate a random number between 0 and 1,r, then I am trying to sum the csum until r is greater than some csum[i], at which point, I want this index. However, I cannot use a for loop.

```
positions = (np.arange(10) + np.random.random()) / 10
r = np.random.rand()
print(r)
csum = np.cumsum(positions)
print(csum)
i = np.sum(r<csum)
print(i)
```

My output was:

```
0.39668465721888346

[0.02797109 0.15594217 0.38391326 0.71188435 1.13985543 1.66782652
 2.2957976  3.02376869 3.85173978 4.77971086]

7
```

How can I get this index correctly without using a for loop?

Comment: check out `np.searchsorted`

Comment: Your code returns the index and does not use a for loop. So what seems to be the problem in your question?